# Create subdirectories named as files in a main directory and move files to corresponding subdirectory

Tags: command-line

I am beginner especially in working with Unix shell.

Is there a way to do following:

1. for each file (around 50) in directory make a subdirectory. Subdirectory should ideally be named as file or as number (from 1-50)
2. Move files to corresponding subdirectories
3. Starting from main directory, for each subdirectory, use file in that subdirectory for further analysis (perform code on it, already written)

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can not have a file and directory with the same name in the same location. But I would always do this over 2 places: the directory where your files are and a destination on the same level as where you do this.(so a script, a dir_toprocess/ and a dir_results/.

Comment: - toss the names into a file `ls > file.txt`, move file.txt to the dir_results  and use `xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p -- < file.txt` to create directories. That covers the creation of the dirs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how, handling funny filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash 
files="$(\
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
        xargs -0 -r stat --format=\"%N\" \
 )"
for i in $files ; do
  mv "$i" "X_$i" && \
    mkdir "$i" && \
    mv "X_$i" "$i/$i"
done

find . -type f -print0 | \
        xargs -0 -r stat --format=\"%N\"
```

Read `man find xargs stat`